# jqGrid BuildSelect giving extra empty options in list

Tags: jqgrid

Using the BuildSelect method to build a dropdown in an edit popup for my jqgrid.  The select list is adding in an extra, empty option for each row.  The empty       is superfluous and I can't figure out where it is coming from.

```
    colModel: [
            { name: "GraftId", key: true, hidden: true },
            { name: "GraftYear", search: true, editable: true },
            { name: "GraftType", search: true, editable: true, edittype: "select",
                editoptions: {
                    dataUrl: getTypesUrl,
                    buildSelect: function (response) {
                        var data = typeof response === "string" ? $.parseJSON(response) : response,                                
                        s = "<select>";
                        $.each(data, function () {
                            s += '<option value="' + this.GraftTypeId + '">' + this.GraftTypeName + '<option>';
                        })
                        return s + "</select>";
                    }
                }
            }
    ]
```

returns:

```
<select role="select" class="FormElement form-control" id="GraftType" name="GraftType" rowid="1">
    <option value="1" role="option">Field Graft</option>
    <option role="option"></option>
    <option value="2" role="option">Field Graft/Barnes</option>
    <option role="option"></option>
    <option value="3" role="option">Field Graft/Larry</option>
    <option role="option"></option>
    <option value="4" role="option">Field Graft/Lisa</option>
    <option role="option"></option>
    <option value="5" role="option">Pot Graft</option>
    <option role="option"></option>
</select>
```

the json string looks fine:

```
[{"GraftTypeId":1,"GraftTypeName":"Field Graft"},{"GraftTypeId":2,"GraftTypeName":"Field Graft/Barnes"},{"GraftTypeId":3,"GraftTypeName":"Field Graft/Larry"},{"GraftTypeId":4,"GraftTypeName":"Field Graft/Lisa"},{"GraftTypeId":5,"GraftTypeName":"Pot Graft"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the closing option tag was missing the slash, so  should have been .  All good now.